# Make a regex upto the end of the string?

Tags: php

I have:

```
$string='#229: Tomato Soup Menu';
preg_match_all('/: (.+?)*/', $string , $arr);
```

I'm trying to make the return just "Tomato Soup Menu".  That is everything after the colon space, until the end of the string.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (it assumes that the format is always consistent at the start - a pound symbol, then numbers, then a colon, then a space, then the text you want):

```
$string='#229: Tomato Soup Menu';
$text = preg_replace('/^#[0-9]+: (.+)/', '$1', $string);
```

If it's just everything after the colon-space, and the start isn't consistent, try this:

```
$string='#229: Tomato Soup Menu';
$text = preg_replace('/^(.*?): (.+)/', '$2', $string);
```

Comment: READER: Check the other reply too for why to use a + and not +?

Comment: For re-factoring. '/: (.*)/' as shown in hakre's answer is nice and short.

Answer (score 3):

You're using a non-greedy regex:

```
(.+?)*
```

This tries to match as little as possible, which for this expression is always nothing.  Try the non-greedy equivalent instead:

```
: (.+)
```

Answer (score 2):

The regular expressions of [`sscanf`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/sscanf) are normally easier to grasp and the function allows you to directly assign the value to a variable:

```
$string='#229: Tomato Soup Menu';
$r = sscanf($string, "#%*d: %[^\n]", $return);
echo $return;
```

This will output `Tomato Soup Menu`, see [Demo](http://codepad.org/xmj92OJv).

If you prefer PCRE syntax, the `$` character matches the end of a string (or end of line in multiline-mode).

```
$string='#229: Tomato Soup Menu';
preg_match_all('/: (.*)$/', $string , $arr);
```

The `.` character does not match end of line anyway in standard mode, so you can even more simplify your pattern:

```
$string='#229: Tomato Soup Menu';
preg_match_all('/: (.*)/', $string , $arr);
```